# How to access properties/methods in other classes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate

I have a RootViewController that has some UITabBarController properties:

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController<LoginViewDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate> {
    UIBarButtonItem*    loginButton;
    NSUserDefaults*     prefs;
    UITabBarController* arTabBarController;
    UITabBarController* stvTabBarController;
    UITabBarController* stTabBarController;
    BOOL                tabBarSaved;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) UIBarButtonItem*    loginButton;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UITabBarController* arTabBarController;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UITabBarController* stvTabBarController;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UITabBarController* stTabBarController;
@property(assign)           BOOL                tabBarSaved;
```

I would like to be able to access these tabbarcontrollers from another class.

**How can I use UIApplication in another class to access the UITabBarControllers and switch tabs?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `@synthesize` in your implementation, then what you're implementing there are public sets of getters and setters.

Which means, if you can get a pointer to your RootViewController here, you can also do anything you want to its `.arTabBarController` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "keyPaths" as well.
Something like:

```
UITabBarController *controller = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] valueForKeyPath:@"delegate.rootViewController.arTabController"];
```

Refer to the [Key-Value Coding Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/KeyValueCoding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107i)